# Selenium WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status from unknown error: missing or invalid 'entry.level'

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a script which uses selenium for testing. Now even opening a Google page using

```
driver.get(url) # url = Google homepage url
```

is giving me below error

```
driver.get("https://my.gumtree.com/login")
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 245, in get
self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unknown error: missing or invalid 'entry.level'
(Session info: chrome=65.0.3315.3)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

I have Google chrome version 65, Chromedriver 2.35 and selenium 2.53.1

I tried different version combinations(mentioned in below table) as per solutions mentioned in other similar questions but nothing worked.

```
Selenium      Chrome      Chromedriver
2.53.0        63           2.33
2.53.1        65(latest)   2.34
3.6.0                      2.35(latest)
3.7.0
3.8.0
3.8.1(latest)
```

EDIT 1: JDK version

```
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: selenium 2 is very outdated.. get on 3.x

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, it was a typo mistake. I have edited the question.

Comment: You error output suggests that you are still using chromedriver=2.29.461591. If you choose to use the most recent browser version with the most recent Selenium , make sure you are using the latest driver version too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unknown error: missing or invalid 'entry.level'
```

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** among the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using **`chromedriver=2.29.461591`** (which is as per the logs, though you mentioned `Chromedriver 2.35` in your question)
- Release Notes of [**`chromedriver=2.29.461591`**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.29/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> **`Supports Chrome v56-58`**

- You are using **`chrome=65.0.3315.3`**
- Release Notes of [**`chromedriver=2.35`**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> **`Supports Chrome v62-64`**

- You are using **`Selenium Version 2.53.1`**.
- Your **`JDK version`** is unknown to us.

### Solution

- Upgrade `JDK` to  recent levels **`JDK Version 8 Update 151`**.
- Upgrade `ChromeDriver` to  **`ChromeDriver v2.35`** level.
- Keep `Chrome` to  **`Chrome v64.x`** levels. ([`as per ChromeDriver v2.35 release notes`](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt))
- Upgrade `Selenium` to  current levels **`Version 3.8.1`**.
- Clean the *Project Workspace* from your *IDE* & *Rebuild All*.
- Run [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores.
- If your Chrome base version is too old, uninstall Chrome through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA Release version of Chrome.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test`.

Comment: JDK is latest as per your suggestions. I downlaoded latest 2.35 chromedriver but still the script is showing it as 2.29. It is in same folder as the script. Hence we can be sure that script is picking the local copy.

Comment: Great !!! Follow the steps : 1) Clean the `Project Workspace` from your IDE & `Rebuild All`. 2) Run `CCleaner` tool to wipe off all the OS chores. 3) If your Chrome base version is too old, uninstall `Chrome` through `Revo Uninstaller` and install a recent `GA Release` version of `Chrome`. 4) Take a `System Reboot`. 5) Execute you `Tests`.

Comment: don't be too sure about that... it depends on PATH

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg Sir, I don't depend on `PATH` settings for any of the WebDriver variants as such. I decide which version of which `WebDriver` variant to pick for my `Tests` and get explicit with the argument `executable_path`. Do you see a drawback in my approach?

Comment: @DebanjanB I was referring to your comment "It is in same folder as the script. Hence we can be sure that script is picking the local copy" (which is not always true).  Placing it in the same folder is different than explicitly passing the location

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg That wasn't mine :) That was OP's comment. Completely agree with you **Hence we can be sure that script is picking the local copy" (which is not always true). Placing it in the same folder is different than explicitly passing the location**

Comment: @DebanjanB, your solution of hardcoding the chromedriver.exe path worked for me. Thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

Go to *http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads*

copy the download link according to your OS

```
wget -N paste_the_link_you_copied
```

unzip it using below command

```
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

Give the permission by the below command

```
chmod +x chromedriver
```

Then follow the below commands, if it says already exists (probabily old version) then go to that path (/usr/local/bin/chromedriver and /usr/bin/chromedriver) and delete chromedriver and run the commands again

```
sudo mv -f chromedriver /usr/local/share/chromedriver
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

Hope this helps. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That error raised beacuse your chrome browser is not compatible with the web driver. If you are using Linux, then simply execute the following command.
sudo apt-get update

Answer (score 1):

Recently I am facing the same problem and take me too much time to figure out what's going on, in my situation facing the problem, I did not close the chrome process after using it, so you should check the process exit or not when you exit the app, this is my last worked Python 3 code demo, hope it will help others:

```
    @staticmethod
    def fetch_music_download_url(music_name: str):
        chrome_driver_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.GOOGLE).install())
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9230")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_driver_service,
                                  options=chrome_options,
                                  executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
        try:
            driver.maximize_window()
            driver.get('http://tool.example.cn/music/?page=audioPage&type=migu&name=' + music_name)
            driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".aplayer-list-download.iconfont.icon-xiazai").click()
            urls = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in
                    driver.execute_script('return document.querySelectorAll(".modal-body a[href*=\'http\']")')]
            for url in urls:
                if "listenSong.do" in url:
                    logger.info("fetched url:" + url)
                    FetchMusic.do_save_music_download_url(url)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("scrapy impl error", e)
        finally:
            driver.stop_client()
            driver.close()
            driver.quit()
            chrome_driver_service.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

upgrading didn't solve my issue but [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/12277) has fixed my issue.

```
try   {
    Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);   }   
catch (WebDriverException ex)   {
    if (Driver.Url == url)
      return;   }
```